# Construct a Binary Tree with Preorder Traversal and store the values in a list

Tags: python, list, global

When I try to append the values to the global list it shows an error。

```
list1 = []

class Node:

    def __init__(self,data):

            self.data = data
            self.left = None
            self.right = None
            self.root = None

        def getData(self):
            return self.data

        def setData(self,data):
            self.data = data

        def insertleft(self,data):
            if self.left == None:
                self.left = Node(data)
                return
            else:
                self.left.setData(data)
                return

        def insertright(self,data):
            if self.right == None:
                self.right = Node(data)
                return
            else:
                self.right.setData(data)
                return

        def insert(self,data):
            if self.data == data:
                return -1
            elif self.data > data:
                self.insertleft(data)
            else:
                self.insertright(data)


        def preorder(self,list1):
            if self.root:
                global list1.append(self.root)
                preorder(self.left,global list1)
                preorder(self.right,global list1)
                return list1



a = Node(99)    
a.insert(10)    
a.insert(101)   
a.insert(108)   
a.insert(9)

print a.preorder(global list1)
```

Comment: Why do you use `global`?

Comment: What error does it throw? Please, always include precise description of what is not working

Comment: I am using a recursive function here and want to append the values to a list, that's the reason I want to use a global list . It says I can't append to the list.     
                                                                                                               "global list1.append(self.root)"                                                                                                              ^